# VBA Variable Range in Look up Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please excuse if it seems simple, Tried to look for the solution, but to no avail. I am trying to execute a formula where visible cells in filtered range shall contain the previous non blank cell value in hidden rows. It gives Application defined or object defined error in Lookup formula line.

**Code :-**

```
With Activehseet
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Range("A1:K" & nlr).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=""
  Range("A1:K" & nlr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="P * Suite *"
  Range("B2:B" & nlr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
  For Each c In Range("B1:B" & nlr).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      n = c.Row - 1
      c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B " & n & "<>""""),$B$2:B" & n & ")"
      
  Next
End With
```

**Approaches Already tried:-**

```
c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B " & n & "<>""),$B$2:B" & n & ")"
```

**and**

```
Set rng = Range("B1:B" & nlr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(" & rng.Address & " <>""),"& rng.Address & " )"
```

None of these seems to work. Any help is highly appreciated !!

Comment: How do you expect your formula to look like for example for `n=5` and did you test that formula in a cell?

Comment: You formula has an extra space after B. `"=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B " ` should be `"=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B"`

Comment: Siddharth - Thanks for looking into this, It still gives the same error,

Comment: Peh - for n = 5, it should look like this.
c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B5<>""),$B$2:B5)"
yes, it is working in excel sheet properly

Comment: As Siddharth wrote `c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B" & n & "<>""""),$B$2:B" & n & ")"` should work then.

Comment: sorry my bad, yes it did work, Thanks a lot Siddharth,,

Comment: Is there a way to upvote the comments ?

Comment: Actually we voted to close the question because it was only a type. That's why there is no official answer (just comments).